# Error during model creation Could not create NativeRL processors. Caused by: Could not find local class in class airport10.Main.actions in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find local class in class airport10.Main.actions

```
at ai.skymind.nativerl.util.Reflect.findLocalClass(Reflect.java:65)

at ai.skymind.nativerl.ActionProcessor.<init>(ActionProcessor.java:33)

at pathmind.policyhelper.AbstractPathmindHelper.init(AbstractPathmindHelper.java:97)

at pathmind.policyhelper.AbstractPathmindHelper.<init>(AbstractPathmindHelper.java:90)

at pathmind.policyhelper.PathmindHelper.<init>(PathmindHelper.java:1155)

at airport10.Main.instantiate_pathmindHelper_xjal(Main.java:772)

at airport10.Main.instantiateBaseStructureThis_xjal(Main.java:1899)

at airport10.Main.<init>(Main.java:1873)

at airport10.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:162)

at airport10.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:1)

at com.anylogic.engine.Experiment.d(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.c(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.g(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.executeCommand(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.a.onCommand(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$null$9(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:112)

at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.c.acceptToAnimationSvgSession(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$startController$10(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:112)

at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)

at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)

at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)

at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.lambda$0(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter.doFilter(QoSFilter.java:201)

at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.doHandle(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Error during model creation:

Could not create NativeRL processors.

Caused by: Could not find local class in class airport10.Main.actions

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create NativeRL processors.

```
at pathmind.policyhelper.AbstractPathmindHelper.init(AbstractPathmindHelper.java:121)

at pathmind.policyhelper.AbstractPathmindHelper.<init>(AbstractPathmindHelper.java:90)

at pathmind.policyhelper.PathmindHelper.<init>(PathmindHelper.java:1155)

at airport10.Main.instantiate_pathmindHelper_xjal(Main.java:772)

at airport10.Main.instantiateBaseStructureThis_xjal(Main.java:1899)

at airport10.Main.<init>(Main.java:1873)

at airport10.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:162)

at airport10.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:1)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find local class in class airport10.Main.actions

```
at ai.skymind.nativerl.util.Reflect.findLocalClass(Reflect.java:65)

at ai.skymind.nativerl.ActionProcessor.<init>(ActionProcessor.java:33)

at pathmind.policyhelper.AbstractPathmindHelper.init(AbstractPathmindHelper.java:97)

... 7 more
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, is there a question here? :) Happy to help with your problem. However, it is really hard to understand what you are trying to ask. Please put some effort into your question and follow advice from https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow as well as https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a good, fast reply :)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for pointing that out. I realize my mistake and will definitely try to take your feedback and improve on my StackOverFlow skills. So I was running a model on Anylogic with Pathmind AI, which was not configured because I do not have the Paid Professional version. Like art_para mentioned, the .jar file is essential to its working. Is there a workaround that you might know??

Answer (score 1):

from this stack trace it looks like you're trying to run a model that depends on a native reinforcement learning java class library provided by Pathmind. This is usually provided as a ".jar" file and should be added to list of model dependencies.

Of course, this is based on my understanding of just the stack trace. If you provide more information regarding you environment and what you're trying to do then I'll be able to help further.

Comment: I was trying to use Pathmind AI to train the model. It turns out I need to have Anylogic Professional not the Evaluation one, to create a standalone application, aka the .jar file. Without the jar file, I will not be able export the model to Pathmind to train it.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to export your AnyLogic model to Pathmind from AnyLogic PLE soon. AnyLogic Professional will not be necessary going forward.

Comment: Please don't invite users to contact off-site support. Answers need to only be self-contained answers to the question.